# PHP function stripcslashes does not convert as desired

Tags: php, string, apache, utf-8, special-characters

Normally executing `echo stripcslashes('Dr\xc3\xa4ger')` should output `Dräger` but when I execute it on my production server with `error_log(stripcslashes('Dr\xc3\xa4ger'))` I just get `Dr\xc3\xa4ger` in the Apache error log.

Can someone please tell me why?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186484/discussion-on-question-by-david-klotz-php-function-stripcslashes-does-not-conver).

Answer (score 2):

So here's what's happening, `stripcslashes('Dr\xc3\xa4ger')` is indeed doing the job you're asking of it, returning `Dräger`. However Apache is [apparently](https://serverfault.com/a/853457/243461) re-escaping it prior to writing it to the error log, which is why it's showing back up there as `Dr\xc3\xa4ger`.

(I would *not* recommend recompiling Apache to disable this, as is recommended elsewhere online.)

Any need to verify that this conversion is happening is something that should be covered by your test suite. (Your tests which cover whatever relies on this, I'm not suggesting you individually test built-in PHP functions.)